# No HDMI audio for MSI X370 Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

Tags: pulseaudio

The laptop is MSI x370 w/AMD-E350 CPU, 4GB RAM. http://www.laptopmag.com/review/laptops/msi-x370.aspx. In the sound device output, there's only one selection (built-in speaker). What needs to be done to enable HDMI audio output? The HDMI video displays fine, but sound comes from built-in speakers.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/268678/no-hdmi-audio-output-from-amd-laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution here, and it works "[No HDMI audio output from AMD Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268678/no-hdmi-audio-output-from-amd-laptop)"

Did a `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` file from this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
```

reboot, and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My keyboard was unable to type within the terminal after using:
"sudo vi /etc/default/grub", but I accomplished via terminal.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

then I changed

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
```

then save and exit gedit, in terminal do

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot

Answer (score -1):

Try to follow [this guide](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/).

If it doesn't work, try to add the PPA for the Nightly Builds for ALSA and install the latest build.

Remove your current ALSA with

`sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`

To add the nightly build repo for ALSA
`sudo add-apt repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily`

Install the latest build and try to restart.

Comment: Well, your tip after uninstall just made me loose my sound forever. The add-apt command doesn't exists and you did not show how to reinstall it.